# ionic: phonegap-push-plugin conflict

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am working with ionic's phonegap-push-plugin 
after installing this plugin I an unable to make build
getting following error:

BUILD FAILED in 0s
21 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 20 up-to-date
(node:30863) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /home/earth/UnicusGit/unicusApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.

I have tried below command for updating version of com.google.android.gms to 10.+.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release --variable PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION=10.+
```

but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For this error, please check your FCm version while installing phonegap plugin, It help me to resolve my conflict.

I have used following command for specifying version of fcm version:
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable FCM_VERSION=17.3.2